# How do I hide the grayed out word prediction feature?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to predict normal words, but I don't want this gray prediction

I was working and I changed something in the settings, I don't remember what it was, and this problem happened, and even when I hit enter it takes me to the next line and doesn't write the prediction. I want a solution that deletes the gray prediction and keeps the normal prediction which comes in the form of an array